# Laravel / Symfony - How can I test confirmations in console commands?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I know I can unit test console commands by passing arguments and options like so:

```
$command->run(new ArrayInput($data), new NullOutput);
```

But what if I want to add a confirmation dialog to my command by using the [**confirm()** method in Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php#L180)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the example on Symfony's site?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/dialoghelper.html#testing-a-command-which-expects-input

If you have but are still having trouble making it work, let us know.

Comment: Oh I missed it! Thank you very much for the link, it was fundamental to figure out the solution :)

Comment: @AndreaMarcoSartori Could you mark this answer as solution?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention I was using PHPSpec for my unit tests.

Finally I figured out how to test confirmations with it.

These are the `use` statements:

```
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet;
```

And this is a sample test:

```
public function it_fires_the_command(QuestionHelper $question, HelperSet $helpers)
{
    // $data is an array containing arguments and options for the console command
    $input = new ArrayInput($data);

    $output = new NullOutput;

    // $query must be an instance of ConfirmationQuestion
    $query = Argument::type('Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion');

    // with "willReturn" we can decide whether (TRUE) or not (FALSE) the user confirms
    $question->ask($input, $output, $query)->willReturn(true);

    // we expect the HelperSet to be invoked returning the mocked QuestionHelper
    $helpers->get('question')->willReturn($question);

    // finally we set the mocked HelperSet in our console command...
    $this->setHelperSet($helpers);

    // ...and run it
    $this->run($input, $output);
}
```